# Error in Alert dialog

Tags: android

There is an error in 'return view' at listview.setOnItemLongClickListener method. The error says cannot return a value from a method with void result type. I am trying to create an alert dialog where it will notify the user whether it wants to delete.

```
package com.example.user.swen;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



import com.example.user.swen.DB.RecordsDataSource;
import com.example.user.swen.Model.Records;

public class Record extends ListActivity {

    public Button NewButton;
    public RecordsDataSource Recordsdatasource;
    ArrayAdapter<Records> RecordAdapter;
    List<Records> records;
    ListView listview;
    Records selectedRecord;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);
        Addrecords();


        //Referencing the Database
        Recordsdatasource = new RecordsDataSource(this);
        Recordsdatasource.open();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Record.this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_record, null);

        //set the listView to use the custom List Adapter
        records = (List<Records>) Recordsdatasource.getAll();
        RecordAdapter = new RecordAdapter(this, 0, (ArrayList<Records>) records);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listview.setAdapter(RecordAdapter);


        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectedRecord = records.get(position);
                AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Record.this);
                a_builder.setMessage("Duty: " + selectedRecord.getType())
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = a_builder.create();
                alert.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#08ae9e'>Information</font>"));
                alert.show();


            }
        });


        listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                selectedRecord = records.get(position);
                AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Record.this);
                a_builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                deleteItem(selectedRecord);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = a_builder.create();
                alert.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#08ae9e'>Alert!!</font>"));
                alert.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }


    public void Addrecords() {
        NewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NewButton);
        NewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent addrecords = new Intent(Record.this, NewRecord.class);
                startActivity(addrecords);
            }
        });
    }


    public static void showToast(Context context, String text) {
        Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void deleteItem(Records selectedRecord) {
        Recordsdatasource.removeRecords(selectedRecord);
        showToast(this, "Usage deleted");
        RecordAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        RecordAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        refreshDisplay();
    }


    private void refreshDisplay() {
        records = Recordsdatasource.getAll();
        RecordAdapter.clear();
        RecordAdapter.addAll(records);
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return a View from your Activity's `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Record.this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_record, null);

    //...

    return view;
}
```

As you can see, `onCreate()` in an Activity has a void return type, meaning you shouldn't be returning anything in this method.

From the looks of your code, you are attempting to use this layout as the Activity's layout, but you are confusing the View inflation code with that used in a Fragment's `onCreateView()` method, which does indeed require you to return a View.

In an Activity, you need to call [`setContentView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)) to set the layout. You can either set the layout using the resource ID via `setContentView(R.layout.activity_record)`, or if you want to inflate the View yourself you can call `setContentView(view)`.

Answer (score 0):

The call `return view` is actually located in `onCreate`. The function `onCreate` is declared to return nothing (void). Therefore, you cannot return an instance of View. You just have to remove that line or replace it with `return;` Also, `onItemLongClick` must return a `boolean`. So you can't move `return view` there either.